# Scala assign to temporary variable in case if clause

Tags: scala

Is there any way to accomplish something like this in Scala?

```scala
foo match {
  case (a, b) if {val bar = expensive_function(); bar.contains(a)} =>
    bar
}
```

I know I could do something like this, but I want `bar` to be local to just the one case, and avoid the use of `var`

```scala
var bar
foo match {
  case (a, b) if {bar = expensive_function(); bar.contains(a)} =>
    bar
}
```

Comment: No, is not possible in general. Sometimes you can do some workarounds, in this case you may compute `bar` before the `match`

Comment: What about using a `lazy val bar` and declaring it before the `match`?

Answer (score 0):

There is no straight forward way like that. If you really need the performance, you can use a custom [extractor](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/extractor-objects.html). Like:

```
object ContainsBar {
  def unapply(s: String) = 
    if (s == "bar") Some(expensive_function(s))
    else None
}

def expensive_function(s: String) = 
  List(s)

val foo: Any = ("bar", "bar")

foo match {
  case (a, ContainsBar(bar)) if bar.contains(a) =>
    bar
}
```

`lazy val` in the comment is a good choice too, although it does come with synchronization penalty and should be used with caution in hot code.